# Casting variables in constructor before calling super?

Tags: java, constructor, casting, super

I am creating a game, and I wish to display the number of lives on the screen. I don't know how to add a number to the screen, but I do know the `GLabel` class which lets you write a `String` on the screen. So I thought this would be a good idea:

```
public class Lives extends GLabel
{
    double xPoistion, yPosition;
    int lives;
    String s_lives;

    public Lives(int lives, double xPosition, double yPosition){
        super(lives, xPosition, yPosition);
        this.lives = lives;
    }
}
```

However the constructor of the `GLabel` class only works with a `String` for the place where `lives` is in the super. I can't seem to find a solution to fix this. Is it even possible?

I tried this:

```
super(lives.toString(s_lives), xPosition, yPosition);
```

result was:

```
Lives.java:14: cannot reference s_lives before supertype constructor has been called
    super(lives.toString(s_lives), xPosition, yPosition);
```

Comment: What is `s_lives`? That's not in the code you've shown. Please show a short but complete program which actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, `lives` is of primitive type `int`. Therefor you cannot call `lives.toString` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are using the class member `s_lives` (I'm assuming that's what `s_lives` is) instead of the passed `lives` parameter, and you are trying to call `toString()` on a primitive.

It looks like what you need is :

```
public Lives(int lives, double xPosition, double yPosition)
{
    super(Integer.toString(lives), xPosition, yPosition);
    this.lives = lives;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me why it is not possible to invoke the toString method on a primitive type integer? Is it because you can only invoke methods on objects?

Comment: @Joop That's right. You can't invoke instance methods on primitives. You can only pass the primitives as parameters to methods.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to convert int to string

```
public class Lives extends GLabel{
    double xPoistion, yPosition;
    int lives;

    public Lives(int lives, double xPosition, double yPosition){
        super(lives+"", xPosition, yPosition);// use '+' operation can easily convert the number
        this.lives = lives;
    }
}
```